# is there a way to get a function to repeat itself if a condition isnt met

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have something like this:

```
static int cantryagain=0;

private void myfunction(){

if (cantryagain==0)
{
    if(variableA=1)
        {
        //do my stuff
        //ta daaaa
        }
        else
        {
        //do something magical that will help make variableA=1 but 
        //if the magic doesnt work i only want it to try once.
        tryagain();
        }
    }
}

private void tryagain
{
    myfunction();
    cantryagain=1; //to make sure the magic only happens once, but 
            //obviously it never gets here as it does
            //myfunction again before it ever can... 
}
```

I know this code is super lame. I'm fairly new to c#.

How could I correctly make something like this?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/c-sharp-cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic

Comment: this wont compile and to do what you are trying look at the while loop

Comment: this is like a homework question

Comment: As an aside, I suggest you read up on the `bool` type

Comment: @ClintonWard - Homework questions are not necessarily discouraged. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/191410

Comment: seems like a lot of people repeat questions on this site and the search func needs improvement. I get a better result searching with google with site:stackoverflow.com <question here>

Comment: @ClintonWard - Maybe that's because Google spends over [$5 billion](http://mwmarketing.co.uk/how-does-google-spend-its-money/) on R&D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to try once more

```
static int cantryagain=0;

private void myfunction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // will loop a max of 2 times
    {
        if(variableA=1)
        {
            //do my stuff
            //ta daaaa
            break; //Breaks out of the for loop so you don't loop a second time
        }
        else if (i == 0)  // Don't bother if this isn't the first iteration
        {
            //do something magical that will help make variableA=1 but 
            //if the magic doesnt work i only want it to try once.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying the previous methods I figured it out myself but my solution was closest to this answer and works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a loop

```
while(somethingNotMet){
    //do something
    somthingNotMet=false;
}
```

Comment: Just to note: `somethingNotMet` is a negative variable name, which is typically frowned upon. See http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228106/211627

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this without using a loop, you can use an optional parameter and call the function recursively:

```
private void myfunction(int recursiveCount = 0)
{
    if (recursiveCount > 1)
    {
      // give up
      return;
    }

    if (variableA == 1)
    {
      //do my stuff
      //ta daaaa
    }
    else
    {
      myFunction(++recursiveCount);
    }
}
```

To use it just call the function without providing the parameter:

`myfunction();`

Comment: recursion is an advanced topic that probably shouldn't be tackled until after the basics have been covered.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a `do while` loop!

```
int attempts = 0;

do
{
     hasWorked = someFunction();
     attempts ++;
}
while(!hasWorked && attempts <= 1)
```

While (lol) I'm here, I thought I'd show you another type of loop, called a `For` loop. This type of loop is used when you know how many times you want your code to run.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.Writeline("Hello there number : " + X);
}
```

This will print out:

```
Hello there number 0
Hello there number 1
Hello there number 2
...
Hello there number 9
```

Comment: Make it a `do while` and lose the first line.

Comment: Wow, that was a daft mistake. Thanks @AshBurlaczenko

Answer (score 0):

yes, you want to put the function in a loop, and have the function return a boolean indicating whether or not it should be run

```
  private bool myFunction() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(0, 100) % 2 == 0; // return true or false, this would be your logic to implement
  }

  public bool doSomething() {
    var tryAgain = false;
    do {
      tryAgain = myFunction(); // when myFunction returns false, the loop condition isn't met, and the loop will exit
    } while (tryAgain);
  }
```